# MySQL unexpectedly returning results for "WHERE integer_column = 'string_value'"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm querying an `INT` column with a string, like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM (`navigation_links`)
WHERE `navigation_links`.`navigation_link_id` =  'anyRandomString'
```

<sup>(originally, this was by accident)</sup>

- Expected results: `0`, because `navigation_link_id` is an `INT`
- Actual results: It seems to return every row whose *value* is `0`

This returns the exact inverse:

```
SELECT id
FROM (`navigation_links`)
WHERE `navigation_links`.`navigation_link_id` !=  'anyRandomString'
```

Here is the table, stripped down:

```
CREATE TABLE `navigation_links` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `navigation_link_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `navigation_group_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Any idea what this is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing values of different types, MySQL will attempt to [convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) one of the values so comparison is possible. In the case of strings and numbers, MySQL will convert the string by interpreting any leading digits as a number. No leading digits corresponds to a numeric value of 0, which makes sense in a couple of ways:

- leading zeros can often be dropped; '042' is the same as '42'. Thus '0' and '' are the same.
- When converting a numeric string to a number, the initial value for the number is 0. The string is iterated over, adding the digits to the number and multiplying by the base:

  ```
  n = 0
  while str[i] is a digit character:
      n += str[i] as a digit
      ++i
  return n
  ```

  If there are no digit characters, the value is 0.
- An empty string is nothing, so the numeric string at the beginning of a string that starts with no digits is nothing. Under this way of thinking, `NULL` could also be the value for a string with no leading digits interpreted as a number. This latter option was not picked by the MySQL developers, possibly to make implementation slightly simpler.

Comment: I see, so it sort of boils down to `0` after each "digit" is checked then?. I noticed that `where int = '3x'` gets cast to `3`, but `where int = 'x3'` gets cast to `0`. I guess the conversion can make sense sometimes, but I'm surprised at this behavior.

Comment: @Madmartigan: note that only leading digits get converted, rather than the first contiguous digit substring. This is the same behavior as the C functions `atoi` and `strtol`; MySQL might use one of these (a quick perusal of the source will tell you whether this is so). You can use the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions to see what number MySQL will convert a string to.